# Azure Functions "Could not load assembly" when running in live environment

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

My function app has a project reference: `MyFA.csproj` --> `MyLibrary.csproj`. When I build, `MyLibrary.dll` is in `bin` folder as expected. But when I test in the live environment I get `Could not load assembly MyLibrary` error. I went to Process Explorer in Kudu and searched for `MyLibrary` and found the dll sitting at

```
w3wp.exe:5328 -> C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mawsFnPlaceholder51_v1\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\26c08606\ff1fbe16\assembly\dl3\05ad04a1\e5a46c4a_273ad401\MyLibrary.DLL
```

but somehow it's not loading when I need it.

Any idea why this is?

Comment: How are you deploying to the live environment?

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi In Visual Studio I just do right-click `Publish` and `MyFA - Web Deploy`

Comment: Just did a quick publish of Http Trigger Function which refers a class library and uses it in the function. Did a Publish from Visual Studio. The class library dll is found inside the bin folder . From Kudu did a "dir" inside the bin folder. The dll is present. The function uses framework 4.6.1.

Comment: @Baskar I discovered that this was the outer exception being thrown, where the root cause was a `JsonException`. I'm running into the same issue from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45444942/serializing-in-azure-function which I believe should be considered a bug.

Comment: Ok. As workaround you can try using "dynamic" avoiding Json serialization and de-serialization if it suits your scenario.